# Can we set email.From in gas application

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am working on a google web-app which send email on certain triggers.

The app is deployed as `Execute the app as: Me(me@gmail.com)`.

However, whenever the mail is sent via other user it always sends From `me@gmail.com`.

and here is the function :-

```
    var subj = "Leave Request From: "+ user.replace(/@google.com/g, "")+ " ["+result[i][1]+" - "+result[i][2]+"]";
       
    var threads = GmailApp.search('\'subject:'+subj+"\'");
       

    threads[0].replyAll("", {
      htmlBody: "Hello "+user.replace(/@google.com/g, "")+", <br><br>"+response +'<br><br>Regards,<br>'+email});
```

Is there a way to send the mail through actual active user instead of me. Is there any function that can do that?

I found a piece of information but not sure if it can be implemented in the web-app.

[image]

Comment: Change "Execute as" to user accessing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A free/consumer Google account can not send an email as coming FROM another account.  The only way that GMail can send an email as coming "FROM" a different account than the one running the code, is to have an alias email set up in a GSuite account, and send the email as coming "FROM" the alias account.  But even then, the default email address can be exposed.  So, if the objective is to hide the default email address of the account running the code, then there is no absolute way to do that that I know of.

The user of your Web App would need to have a GSuite account, or paid Google account that allows sending an email as coming from an alias.  Then the user of your Web App would need to be logged in to their account, and your Web App needs to be configured to run "As" the user accessing the Web App.

So, there are multiple conditions that must be met in order to send an email as coming "FROM" a different email address than the default address.

Plus, the user would need to authorize permission for the code to run as if running from their account, AND the code would need to have broad access to make settings in their GMail account.  That's a huge problem, because your Web App would be able to delete all their emails, read all their emails, and make settings in their Gmail account.  That is considered a very great security risk.  So, your Web App would be considered a security risk, that could do lots of bad things to the user's account.

If you wanted to make your Web App available to the public, and have more than 100 users, then you'd need to apply to Google to have your Apps Script project, that the Web App is based on, be approved by Google.

Your code would need to check whether the user account had a valid email alias set up, or the code could fail.  You'd need to provide detailed instructions to the user about how to set up and validate an alias email in their account.